# How should I be managing class dependencies/refactoring?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, plugin-architecture

My application implements a modular architecture that can dynamically load one or more "plugin" assemblys. Each assembly contains a class implementing an `IPlugin` interface, providing various methods and properties that the host app uses to interact with the plugin.

This class inevitably has dependencies on other classes within the plugin, and these may in turn have their own dependencies. So far I've been managing all this using Castle Windsor (each plugin contains an `IWindsorInstaller` where I register its dependencies), and doing DI via their constructors. The downside is that the classes have to be `public` for this approach to work.

I've now come to my senses and want to lock down the plugin by making all these classes `internal`, however I'm not sure of the best way to do handle the dependencies as presumably I won't be able to use Windsor. I don't want the classes to instantiate their own dependencies (not loosely-coupled, lack of testability, etc.), so what other approaches are there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The downside is that the classes have to be public for this approach
>   to work.

This is not true. You can register stuff that is internal, but you'll probably loose the auto-wiring (automatic constructor injection) feature of Castle Windsor (or any DI container for that matter). You can register internal stuff by registering delegates that create those types manually. For instance:

```cs
container.Register(Component.For<IService>()
    .UsingFactoryMethod(() =>
    {
        var log = container.Resolve<ILogger>();
        return new RealService(log);
    })
    .LifeStyle.Transient);
```

Manually creating services with `new` is suboptimal, since auto-wiring keeps the composition root of your plug in assembly the most maintainability, but I don't think there is a good alternative in your situation. Still, this is better than letting each service create its own dependencies (poor man's DI).

**UPDATE**

I remembered something: It should be possible to still do auto-wiring with internal types, when you register those internal types using the generic methods, such as this one:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IService>()
    .ImplementedBy<RealService());
```

For this to work, the constructor of `RealService` has to be public (but `RealService` itself can be internal). This even works in a **partial trust**, such as when running in the very restrictive the Silverlight sandbox (or at least, it works with Simple Injector, but Castle should be able to do this as well).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I also realised today that I can register internal types that have a public ctr. It raises another "design" question though - I'm currently injecting these dependencies into the ctr of my IPlugin class. However the class can be thought of as a public API in to the plugin, so it feels wrong having these ctr parameters in there. If I removed them what would be the alternative to resolving its dependencies? Use a service locator?

Comment: If your plugin library is shipped to customers who might use it in several ways, it might be inconvenient for them when your public API has a constructor with those dependencies, but for usage within your own company (where you know a DI container is used) this won't probably be a problem. In both cases you can also make that type internal and use a `PluginFactory` class that consumers can interact to. Or use both a public plugin class and factory.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Ninject, you can add a [NinjectModule](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Modules-and-the-Kernel) to each assembly which configures the bindings and then in the host application simply load the modules to register the bindings.

```
public class ServiceModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load() 
    {
        Bind<IService>().To<RealService>();
    }
}
```

The `RealService` can stay internal and the module can see it because it is inside the same assembly.

Comment: From what I've read the NinjectModule is essentially the same as IWindsorInstaller, which I'm already using. See above answer from Steven and my subsequent comment regarding internal classes.

Comment: Isn't the problem that IWindsorInstaller requires the class to be public though? Ninject doesn't, I use this approach myself with a public interface, internal implementation and a public NinjectModule with the bindings registered in it.

Comment: Just tested Ninject in a Silverlight sandbox. When making `Service` internal (with a public ctor) I get the following exception: "MethodAccessException: Attempt by method 'DynamicClass.DynamicInjector724..963(System.Object[])' to access method `SilverApp.Service..ctor(SilverApp.ILogger)' failed.". After making `Service` public, it works as expected. I must conclude that it doesn't work in Ninject. However, it might still work in a partial trust web application.

Comment: That's useful to know, I haven't used it in a partial trust environment.

Comment: @Steven just a thought, would it work if you added http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx to your class library?

Comment: @Trevor  that only work when you'd add that attribute to Ninject dll, but still not have impact in Silverlight.

Comment: @Steven, I'm not sure what you mean by that, have a look at the section advanced features here http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart (about 1/3rd down the page) I use that trick to create mocks of interals for my unit tests so I don't have to make them public

Comment: @TrevorPilley: For the test I ran in Silverlight I used a an internal type that was located in the same assembly as the as where I built the assembly. Tell me in which assembly the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute should be placed. btw, don't forget that that this attribute does not exist in Silverlight. Because Silverlight is partial-trust only.

Comment: @Steven Ah OK, I apply it to the assembly containing the types (e.g. the class library that the internal classes/interfaces are defined in), apparently the attribute is is available in Silverlight http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: @TrevorPilley: Apparently I was looking at the wrong docs. You are right. The attribute does exist in Silverlight.

Comment: Still, I wonder why your answer is downvoted. I'll compensate it.